# Multiple certificates for Apple developers

Tags: selenium, safari

I would like to run selenium tests on many VMs which also contain a Safari browser. I just signed up for Apple's Safari Developer Program like it's said here: 
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/SafariDriver

I also generated a certificate an built my SafariDriver extension. Everything worked well on one machine but now I would like to generate the SafariDriver extension for other machines as well.

Do I have to sign up as another Apple developer?

Answer (score 0):

My experience has been that you are able create two safari extension certs with one safari dev account.  Not sure if paying for a dev account let's u have more.